# Android JCIFS/SMB does not work on network without internet

Tags: android, smb, wifi, jcifs

I'm working on an Android App that writes and reads files (*.txt) on a Windows PC. The App connects to a WiFi network and uses the SMB. The App works pretty well while the network has internet connection. When I disconnect Internet, the App can't connect to the PC. I mean, the device remains connected to the network on a WLAN, but there is no internet access on that network, and the App then can't connect to the folder on the Windows PC.
I've searched on internet if this is a problem in the JCIFS library or Android system, and I found no information about it. So, maybe anyone has experienced this before? Is there any solution?

Here is some information about my project:

JCIFS - 1.3.18

Android Device 4.1.2 (16)

Android Manifest permissions - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"`

I've tried with ES File Explorer in the same scenario, connected to a WiFi network without Internet connection, then I searched for PCs in LAN and a message has been showed up: "Connect to a WLAN first".

Maybe is Android's fault?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JCIFS library (the use of SMB in this case) uses a valid DNS to resolve names. Therefore, if there is no internet connection, SMB cannot resolve the name of the host to which you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.resolveOrder","BCAST,DNS");`

I use the above. The default order of LMHOSTS, WINS, BCAST, then DNS causes very long pauses waiting for a timeout when just on a LAN.